# How to write test case using NUnit which has a dependency of interfaces?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public List<CustomerViewModel> GetResellerCustomersWithProperties(string shortCode)
        {            
            var businessManager = DependencyContainer.GetInstance<ICortexBusinessManager>();
            return businessManager.GetResellerCustomersWithProperties(shortCode); 
        }
```

How do we write Test case using Nunit which has a dependency from interfaces.

Comment: [Mock them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627371/how-do-you-use-moq-to-mock-a-simple-interface) <- (clickable).

Comment: You have a design problem here.... Dependencies should not be resolved per method basis. You should be using constructor based dependency injection. It will be easier to mock the dependencies and unit testing.

Answer (score 6):

Dependency Injection is your friend here.
Note You will need an IOC container, such as Autofac, Unity, StructureMap etc...  wired up with your application.

Inject your dependencies in the constructor of your class:

```
public class CustomerService 
{
    private ICortexBusinessManager _cortexBusinessManager;

    public CustomerService (ICortexBusinessManager cortexBusinessManager)
    {
        _cortexBusinessManager = cortexBusinessManager;
    }

    public List<CustomerViewModel> GetResellerCustomersWithProperties(string shortCode)
    {            
        return _cortexBusinessManager.GetResellerCustomersWithProperties(shortCode); 
    }
}
```

You can then use a mocking framework within your unit test to mock calls to your interface.

Example below uses [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

```
public class CustomerServiceTest
{
    [Test]
    public void GetResellerCustomersWithProperties_ReturnsFromCortextBusinessManager()
    {
        //arrange
        var mockCortexBusinessManager = new Mock<ICortexBusinessManager>();

        //if GetResellerCustomersWithProperties is called with s123, return a new list of CustomerViewModel
        //with one item in, with id of 1
        mockCortexBusinessManager.Setup(m=> m.GetResellerCustomersWithProperties("s123"))
            .Returns(new List<CustomerViewModel>(){new CustomerViewModel{Id = 1}});


        var customerService = new CustomerService(mockCortexBusinessManager.Object);

        //act
        var result = customerService.GetResellerCustomersWithProperties("s123");

        //assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count())
        Assert.AreEqual(1, result.FirstOrDefault().Id)
    }
}
```